# Can't read from database using Entity Framework 5

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

Im trying to read records from a database using Entity Framework , which I have not used before.

Im trying to run the load rule method:

```
class Rule
    {
        private STRATCODE stratCode;
        private STRATRULEDEF stratRuleDef;
        AREEntities AREDb = new AREEntities();

        public Rule(STRATRULEDEF StratRuleDef, STRATCODE StratCode)
        {
            this.stratRuleDef = StratRuleDef;
            this.stratCode = StratCode;    
        }

        public void LoadRule()
        {
            var query = from stratCode in AREDb.STRATCODES
                        where stratCode.CODEVALUE == "49300"
                        select stratCode;

            //StratCodeRepository StratCodeRepository = new StratCodeRepository(new AREEntities());
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\user\Desktop\NewText.txt",true))
            {
                foreach (STRATCODE row in query)
                {
                    file.WriteLine("{0} | {1} | {2} | {3} | {4} | {5}", stratCode.STRATRULEKEY, stratCode.CODETYPE, stratCode.CODEVALUE, stratCode.SYSTEMID, stratCode.CODESETKEY, stratCode.PAYMENTYEAR);
                }
            }
        }
```

My problem is that everytime I run it, it returns the right number of records but all of the data in the text file is empty and I can find no clues in my output log.

```
0 |  |  |  |  | 
0 |  |  |  |  | 
0 |  |  |  |  | 
0 |  |  |  |  | 
0 |  |  |  |  |
```

Any ideas? I dont know how to even start with no clues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your write is not using the foreach variable:

```
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\stephen.carmody\Desktop\NewText.txt", true))
    {
        foreach (var row in query)
        {
            file.WriteLine("{0} | {1} | {2} | {3} | {4} | {5}",
                row.STRATRULEKEY,
                row.CODETYPE, 
                row.CODEVALUE, 
                row.SYSTEMID, 
                row.CODESETKEY, 
                row.PAYMENTYEAR);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Haha Thanks for the help, so easy yet I never would have seen it